# How i can change the padding inside the bootstrap-vue datepicker?

Tags: css, vue.js, datepicker, bootstrap-vue

i have huge problem's with the bootstrap-vue component b-form-datepicker. 
The padding of the date-button's is to big. This caused a linebreak at Sunday, as you in the picture below. Has anyone an idea to fix this problem? [Broken Datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6mZx.png)

The code:

```
<div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        Until:
                        <b-form-datepicker class="mb-2" v-model="form.endDate" :min="new Date(form.startDate)" locale="de"></b-form-datepicker>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thank u and nice evening.

Comment: Hey, and welcome to stackOverflow. You need to give us some more code in order for us to effectively help you out, mate. This issue is like a needle in the haystack atm

Comment: Are you including BootstrapVue's custom SCSS/CSS after Bootstrap v4.4's SCSS/CSS? BootstrapVue's custom styles are needed for correct formatting of the calendar/datepicker.